# Get the last row of a previous group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is what my data table looks like:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
    Product  Group    LastProductOfPriorGroup
    A          1          NA
    B          1          NA
    C          2          B
    D          2          B
    E          2          B
    F          3          E
    G          3          E
')
```

The `LastProductOfPriorGroup` column is my desired column. I am trying to fetch the product from last row of the prior group. So in the first two rows, there are no prior groups and therefore it is `NA`. In the third row, the product in the last row of the prior group 1 is `B`. I am trying to accomplish this by

```
dt[,LastGroupProduct:= shift(Product,1), by=shift(Group,1)]
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do

```
dt[, newcol := shift(dt[, last(Product), by = Group]$V1)[.GRP], by = Group]
```

This results in the following updated `dt`, where `newcol` matches your desired column with the unnecessarily long name. ;)

```
   Product Group LastProductOfPriorGroup newcol
1:       A     1                      NA     NA
2:       B     1                      NA     NA
3:       C     2                       B      B
4:       D     2                       B      B
5:       E     2                       B      B
6:       F     3                       E      E
7:       G     3                       E      E
```

Let's break the code down from the inside out.  I will use `...` to denote the accumulated code:

- `dt[, last(Product), by = Group]$V1` is getting the last values from each group as a character vector.
- `shift(...)` shifts the character vector in the previous call
- `dt[, newcol := ...[.GRP], by = Group]` groups by `Group` and uses the internal `.GRP` values for indexing

**Update:** Frank brings up a good point about my code above calculating the shift for every group over and over again.  To avoid that, we can use either

```
shifted <- shift(dt[, last(Product), Group]$V1)
dt[, newcol := shifted[.GRP], by = Group]
```

so that we don't calculate the shift for every group.  Or, we can take Frank's nice suggestion in the comments and do the following.

```
dt[dt[, last(Product), by = Group][, v := shift(V1)], on="Group", newcol := i.v]
```

Comment: You are using by=Group 2 times. What is the 1st one doing vs the 2nd one? and what is the significance of $V1?

Comment: @gibbz00 - I added some explanation.  Hope it helps.

Comment: You are computing `shift(dt[, last(Product), by = Group]$V1)` again and again for each group. I would probably do `dt[dt[, last(Product), by = Group][, v := shift(V1)], on="Group", newcol := i.v]`

Comment: @Frank -  I think `shifted <- shift(dt[, last(Product), Group]$V1); 
dt[, newcol := shifted[.GRP], by = Group]` would also be okay then, since it's outside the data table call.

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to save the last group's value in a variable.

```
this = NA_character_    # initialize
dt[, LastProductOfPriorGroup:={ last<-this; this<-last(Product); last }, by=Group]
dt
   Product Group LastProductOfPriorGroup
1:       A     1                      NA
2:       B     1                      NA
3:       C     2                       B
4:       D     2                       B
5:       E     2                       B
6:       F     3                       E
7:       G     3                       E
```

NB: `last()` is a `data.table` function which returns the last item of a vector (of the Product column in this case).

This should also be fast since no logic is being invoked to fetch the last group's value; it just relies on the groups running in order (which they do).