# Order of evaluation is not sequential in `j`

Tags: r, data.table

Referring to [dplyr group by, carry forward value from previous group to next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126224/dplyr-group-by-carry-forward-value-from-previous-group-to-next/47209858#47209858) and [Get the last row of a previous group in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285789/get-the-last-row-of-a-previous-group-in-data-table/42427568#42427568) on how to code a recursive calculation, I noticed that the order of evaluation is not sequential within `j`

Example using a simple sum of previous and current row to demonstrate the issue hence I am not asking about using `shift`:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.8 R-3.6.1 Win x64
DT <- data.table(rn=1:4, X=c(0,0,1,0), Y=c(0,0,0,0))

DT[, { 
    A <- X[1L]
    B <- X[1L]
    .SD[-1L,
        {
            print(.BY$rn)
            print(c(X=X, A=A, B=B))

            #expecting the next 4 lines to be evaluated in sequence but seems like B <- X is evaluated before these 2 lines
            sA <- A + Y  #line 1
            sB <- B + Y  #line 2

            B <- X       #line 3
            A <- copy(X) #line 4

            print(c(X=X, A=A, B=B))
            .(sA, sB)
        },
        rn]
}]
```

output:

```
[1] 2
X A B 
0 0 0 
X A B 
0 0 0 
[1] 3
X A B 
1 0 1<- this should be 0 
X A B 
1 1 1 
[1] 4
X A B 
0 1 0<- this should be 1 
X A B 
0 0 0
```

I am expecting the 4 lines to be evaluated in sequence but seems like `B <- X` is evaluated before the first 2 lines. Using `copy` solves the issue (i.e. `A <- copy(X)`). Should this be a bug or desired behaviour?

Comment: Please fill it in github, if possible simplify, instead of print you can use `stopifnot(all.equal())` so we can turn that into unit tests more easily.