# adding missing dates into a data table based on some conditions in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like this :

```
timestamp    Status
05-01-2020    0
06-01-2020    0
07-01-2020    1
08-01-2020    1
09-01-2020    1
11-01-2020    0
13-01-2020    1
```

If The status is `1` and status `0` are appearing on two different days, then I need to fill the missing dates. Here on 9th last value of status is `1` and it is becoming `0` on 11th only. So in between I have 10th. I need to add these dates to the existing data table  or create a new data table and put status as `1`

I am aware of this :

```
library(tidyverse)

complete(dt, status, timestamp)
```

Expected output:

```
 timestamp    Status
    05-01-2020    0
    06-01-2020    0
    07-01-2020    1
    08-01-2020    1
    09-01-2020    1
    10-01-2020    1
    11-01-2020    0
    13-01-2020    1
```

This should repeat for any number of days in between. But only for conditions between `1 and 0` and not between `0 and 1`

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question. If I understand correctly, the OP asks to insert additional rows between each group of contiguous values of `Status` if the previuos group had `Status == 1` and the current group has `Status == 0`. In addtion, I understand that filling up missing dates *within* a streak of `Status == 1` is *not* requested.

So here are two different `data.table` approaches:

#### 1. Grouping and prepending additional rows to each `Status == 0` group

This solution borrows from [Matt Dowle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427568/3817004) to [Get the last row of a previous group in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38285789/3817004) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209858/3817004) for another use case).

It creates groups of contiguous streaks of 0/1 values in `Status` (using `rleid()`). For each group, it is checked whether it is required to insert rows. If so, the additional rows are prepended to the rows of the current group (using `rbind()`).

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
dt[, timestamp := as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")]   # coerce character date to numeric 
dt[, grp := rleid(Status)]   # create groups of consecutive values of Status
dt[, new := ""]   # just for test & demonstration
pg <- first(dt)  # initialise storage of last row of previous group
dt[, {
  if (first(timestamp) - pg$timestamp > 1L & pg$Status == 1L) {
    # if there is a gap and Status switches from 1 to 0 the fill the gap
    add <- .(timestamp = seq(pg$timestamp + 1L, first(timestamp) - 1L, by = 1L), Status = 1L, new = "*")
  } else {
    # no gap to fill
    add <- .SD[0L]
  }
  pg <- last(.SD)   # remember last row
  rbind(add, .SD)   # prepend additional rows
}, by = grp][, grp := NULL][]   # remove grouping variable
```

> ```
>      timestamp Status    new
>         <IDat>  <int> <char>
>  1: 2020-01-05      0       
>  2: 2020-01-06      0       
>  3: 2020-01-07      1       
>  4: 2020-01-08      1       
>  5: 2020-01-09      1       
>  6: 2020-01-10      1      *
>  7: 2020-01-11      0       
>  8: 2020-01-13      1       
>  9: 2020-01-14      0       
> 10: 2020-01-16      1       
> 11: 2020-01-17      1       
> 12: 2020-01-18      1      *
> 13: 2020-01-19      1      *
> 14: 2020-01-20      0
> ```

Note that an enhanced dataset has been used (see below) to allow for a more thoroughly testing. Also, the column `new` has been added just to demonstrate where the rows have been inserted.

#### 2. Identify gaps, create missing rows, append and re-order

This approach is different. It identifies the gaps which are to be filled, creates the missing rows, appends them to the original dataset, and re-orders the rows by timestamp:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
library(magrittr)   # piping used to improve readability
dt[, timestamp := as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")] # coerce character date to numeric
lapply(
  dt[, .I[timestamp - shift(timestamp, fill = first(timestamp)) > 1L & shift(Status) == 1 & Status == 0]], 
  function(i) dt[, .(timestamp = seq(timestamp[i - 1L] + 1L, timestamp[i] - 1L, by = 1L), Status = 1L)]
) %>% 
  c(list(dt)) %>% 
  rbindlist() %>% 
  .[order(timestamp)]
```

> ```
>      timestamp Status
>         <IDat>  <int>
>  1: 2020-01-05      0
>  2: 2020-01-06      0
>  3: 2020-01-07      1
>  4: 2020-01-08      1
>  5: 2020-01-09      1
>  6: 2020-01-10      1
>  7: 2020-01-11      0
>  8: 2020-01-13      1
>  9: 2020-01-14      0
> 10: 2020-01-16      1
> 11: 2020-01-17      1
> 12: 2020-01-18      1
> 13: 2020-01-19      1
> 14: 2020-01-20      0
> ```

The expression

```
dt[, .I[timestamp - shift(timestamp, fill = first(timestamp)) > 1L & shift(Status) == 1 & Status == 0]]
```

identifies the gaps to be filled by returning the indices in the original dataset `dt` where the additional rows need to be inserted *before*.

> ```
> [1]  6 11
> ```

So, the additional rows need to be inserted between rows 5 to 6, and 10 to 11, resp.

#### 3. Data

The dataset has been expanded to allow for a more thoroughly testing.

```
dt <- fread(
  "timestamp    Status
05-01-2020    0
06-01-2020    0
07-01-2020    1
08-01-2020    1
09-01-2020    1
11-01-2020    0
13-01-2020    1
14-01-2020    0
16-01-2020    1
17-01-2020    1
20-01-2020    0")
```

Note that all solutions posted so far assume that `dt` is ordered by increasing `timestamp`. If not, it can be achieved by

```
setorder(dt, timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using rolling join to find the date before the closing zero and then fill up the missing dates for each continuous set of ones:

```
DT[Status==1L, nextzero := 
    DT[Status==0L][.SD, on=.(timestamp), roll=-Inf, x.timestamp - 1L]
]

ans <- rbindlist(list(
        DT[Status==1L & !is.na(nextzero), 
            .(timestamp=seq(min(timestamp), nextzero, by="1 day"), Status=1L),
            nextzero],
        DT[Status==0L | is.na(nextzero)]
    ), use.names=TRUE)[, nextzero := NULL]

setorder(ans, timestamp)[]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("timestamp    Status
05-01-2020    0
06-01-20200    
07-01-2020    1
08-01-2020    1
09-01-2020    1
11-01-2020    0
13-01-2020    1")
DT[, timestamp := as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Added some more rows to your data to include the case of more than one missing day.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

  df %>%
    mutate(timestamp = as.Date(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
         to_fill = case_when(Status == 1L & lead(Status) == 0L & difftime(lead(timestamp), timestamp, "days") > 1 ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
    complete(timestamp = seq.Date(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), by = "day")) %>%
    fill(to_fill) %>%
    mutate(Status = case_when(is.na(Status) & to_fill == 1 ~ 1L,
                            TRUE ~ Status)) %>%
    na.omit() %>% 
    select(-to_fill)

#> # A tibble: 14 x 2
#>    timestamp  Status
#>    <date>      <int>
#>  1 2020-01-05      0
#>  2 2020-01-06      0
#>  3 2020-01-07      1
#>  4 2020-01-08      1
#>  5 2020-01-09      1
#>  6 2020-01-10      1
#>  7 2020-01-11      0
#>  8 2020-01-13      1
#>  9 2020-01-15      1
#> 10 2020-01-16      1
#> 11 2020-01-17      1
#> 12 2020-01-18      0
#> 13 2020-01-19      0
#> 14 2020-01-22      1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = c("05-01-2020", "06-01-2020", "07-01-2020", "08-01-2020", "09-01-2020", "11-01-2020", "13-01-2020", "15-01-2020", "18-01-2020", "19-01-2020", "22-01-2020"),
                 Status = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L ))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can filter the rows which we want to expand. The condition to select rows is if current row `Status` is 1 and next row `Status` is 0 OR current row `Status` is 1 and previous row's `Status` is 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y')

temp <- df %>% 
        filter(Status == 1 & lead(Status) == 0 | lag(Status) == 1 & Status == 0)
```

Then create groups of two rows in that dataframe and expand them filling the dates between them and updating `Status` as 1. Once we have expanded dataset we can bind it with the original dataset to get complete dataset.

```
temp %>%  
   group_by(grp = rep(1:n(), each = 2, length.out = n())) %>%
   tidyr::complete(timestamp = seq(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), by = 'day'), 
                   fill = list(Status = 1)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp) %>%
   bind_rows(anti_join(df, temp)) %>%
   arrange(timestamp)


# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  timestamp  Status
#  <date>      <dbl>
#1 2020-01-05      0
#2 2020-01-06      0
#3 2020-01-07      1
#4 2020-01-08      1
#5 2020-01-09      1
#6 2020-01-10      1
#7 2020-01-11      0
#8 2020-01-13      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary data frame which is complete in sense of dates and which `Status` column is `1`.

```
dat$timestamp <- as.Date(dat$timestamp, format="%d-%m-%Y")  ## date format is needed
tmp <- data.frame(timestamp=seq(dat$timestamp[1], by="day", length.out=nrow(dat)),
           Status=1)
```

Then use `match` to `rbind` that row where the lagged `diff` is `-1`.

```
dat <-
  rbind(dat, 
        tmp[match(dat$timestamp[match(-1, c(diff(dat$Status), NA))] + 1, tmp$timestamp), ])
dat[order(dat$timestamp), ]  
#     timestamp Status
# 1  2020-01-05      0
# 2  2020-01-06      0
# 3  2020-01-07      1
# 4  2020-01-08      1
# 5  2020-01-09      1
# 61 2020-01-10      1
# 6  2020-01-11      0
# 7  2020-01-13      1
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- read.table(text="timestamp    Status
05-01-2020    0
06-01-2020    0
07-01-2020    1
08-01-2020    1
09-01-2020    1
11-01-2020    0
13-01-2020    1", header=T)
```